# Why doesn't position: sticky work on my header?

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am using `position: sticky;` for my header, but it does not seem to work. The error is that the navigation bar doesn't stay in place when I scroll down, like it should with `position: sticky` set.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .32);
}

#navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Antonio;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #33C4C4;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

li a:hover {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#dropdown-other {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: #33C4C4 1.5px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#dropdown-other a {
  color: #33C4C4;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

#dropdown-other a:hover {
  color: black;
}

#other:hover #dropdown-other {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 790px) {
  .nav-section {
    display: none !important;
  }
  #expand {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  .overflowDropdown {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav style="position: sticky; position: -webkit-sticky; top: 0px; z-index: 10;">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="Images/logo.png" id="logo" title="LOGO" />
    </a>
    <ul align="right" id="navigation">
      <li><a class="nav-section" href="#" title="HOME PAGE">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-section" href="#" title="SHOP PAGE">SHOP</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-section" href="#" title="PEOPLE PAGE">PEOPLE</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-section" href="#" title="ABOUT PAGE">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li id="other">
        <a href="#" title="OTHER PAGES">OTHER</a>
        <div id="dropdown-other">
          <div class="overflowDropdown">
            <a href="#">HOME</a>
            <a href="#">SHOP</a>
            <a href="#">PEOPLE</a>
            <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
          </div>
          <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
          <a href="#">FEED</a>
          <a href="#">BOARD</a>
          <a href="#">CHANGELOG</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<p style="margin-top: 700px;">test</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of the ***div*** enclosing it around. Your alternatives:

- Make the ***parent div sticky*** as demonstrated.
- ***Remove*** the div and the ***nav*** would be sticky (since no parent container).
- Take the ***nav*** out of the div if the div is required.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .32);
  z-index: 10;
}

#navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Antonio;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #33C4C4;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

li a:hover {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#dropdown-other {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: #33C4C4 1.5px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#dropdown-other a {
  color: #33C4C4;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

#dropdown-other a:hover {
  color: black;
}

#other:hover #dropdown-other {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 790px) {
  .nav-section {
    display: none !important;
  }
  #expand {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  .overflowDropdown {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="position: -webkit-sticky;position: sticky;top: 0px;">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="Images/logo.png" id="logo" title="LOGO" />
    </a>
    <ul align="right" id="navigation">
      <li><a class="nav-section" href="#" title="HOME PAGE">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-section" href="#" title="SHOP PAGE">SHOP</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-section" href="#" title="PEOPLE PAGE">PEOPLE</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-section" href="#" title="ABOUT PAGE">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li id="other">
        <a href="#" title="OTHER PAGES">OTHER</a>
        <div id="dropdown-other">
          <div class="overflowDropdown">
            <a href="#">HOME</a>
            <a href="#">SHOP</a>
            <a href="#">PEOPLE</a>
            <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
          </div>
          <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
          <a href="#">FEED</a>
          <a href="#">BOARD</a>
          <a href="#">CHANGELOG</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<p style="margin-top: 700px;">test</p>
```

Comment: This is missing the most sensible solution as an option, which is to put the rest of the page's content inside the wrapping `<div>` element.

Comment: @TylerH Do you see  this "Take the nav out of the div if the div is required." And if you noticed, the OP has content outside of the nav's parent div, so I just provided alternative which manipulate the structure of rest of the content the least (or not at all)

Comment: @TylerH The sensible solution might be sensible for this sample snippet (as it just contains 1 <p></p> outside the div), but that might just mess up the rest of the content's CSS. Anyways, thanks for your input :)

Comment: Yes I see it, and I said the most sensible solution is the opposite; put everything in the div. As far as we can tell the "other content" outside the div is just placeholder content and the wrapping div has no styles whatsoever, so it makes sense to be semantic and put the wrapper around all the things like wrappers are designed for.