# How to make child header element sticky with footer of unknown height at bottom of viewport or below

Tags: css, flexbox, sticky-footer

I have a fiddle to describe my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/ajbrun/yaq13ghu/7/

I would like to have the footer of unknown height (green) always at the bottom of the page or below (if pushed by content). I would also like to have the yellow navbar stuck to the top of the page after scrolling past the red header banner. Unfortunately, I can't get both of these scenarios to happen together.

Using my example, the header navbar is sticky if flexbox is commented out, but that stops the footer from being positioned at the bottom of the viewport when there's no content. With flexbox enabled, the header navbar is no longer sticky, but the footer works as I'd like.

Is there a way I can make both scenarios work together?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Without this line, the yellow navbar is sticky. With it, the footer is sticky. */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}

.header__banner {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.header__navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

main {
  height: 500px;
  /* Amend this to simulate content */
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header__banner">

  </div>
  <div class="header__navbar">

  </div>
</header>
<main>

</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding this, so you want the yellow to be a sticky when scroll as well as the green to be permanently at the bottom? If so, using your fiddle, removing the `display: flex` does this. Whats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove `<header>` to get your goal.

```html
<div class="header__banner">

</div>
<div class="header__navbar">

</div>
<main>

</main>
<footer></footer>
```

It can make navbar sticky, and also make `<footer>` at the bottom while `<main>` is 0 height.

What's more, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038799/why-doesnt-position-sticky-work-on-my-header)

Or, if you rellay want to keep `<header>`, a solution is, making `<header>` sticky, and using js to listen `scroll` event, so when user scroll down, the `header__banner`'s `height` will reduce:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.header__banner {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header__navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

main {
  height: 1500px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY
  let height = 50 - last_known_scroll_position
  if (height < 0) height = 0
  document.getElementsByClassName("header__banner")[0].style.height = height + "px"
});
```

Comment: That would go against the BEM principles I've been following. I'm aiming to keep header (which would have a header class in actuality) as the block (B) and banner and navbar would be child elements (E). Is there a way for this to work with no reduction in markup (perhaps additions instead)?

Comment: @ajbrun A solution is, making `<header>` sticky, and using js to listen scroll event, so when user scroll down, the `header__banner`'s `max-height` will reduce.

Answer (score 0):

Sora's suggestion gave me an idea.

Although I didn't want to delete my header markup element, I remembered there was a `display: contents` css property. Adding this to the header in place of display inline seemed to do the trick. It had the affect of keeping the element whilst gain the affect of it not being there (as per Sora's suggestion).

https://jsfiddle.net/ajbrun/jfq8gznk/6/

The only issue is current Edge doesn't support this property until version 76 is released with Chromium (maybe end of this year). I've therefore added an @supports which does a similar job. Only issue is I'd need to support the "old way" of doing it using assumed heights until support is better.